# What is wrong with this query it does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

List the name, id and expertise of all staff who have the same expertise as those currently in the Poole Office

Schema:

Office(Office_ID, Office_Location)

Staff(S_ID, S_Name, S_Expertise, Office_ID*)

I did

```
SELECT S_Name, S_ID, S_Expertise
FROM Staff
WHERE S_Expertise IN(SELECT Office_Location
                     FROM Office
                     WHERE Office_Location = 'Poole Office');
```

Comment: What means "it does not work"?

Comment: Says my query is incorrect

Comment: Does this sound right to you: `S_Expertise IN(SELECT Office_Location`?

Comment: No, what should it be?

Comment: Join `Office` and `Staff` in `in` section for 'Poole Office' and select `S_Expertise`.

Comment: The requirement is not clear, it sounds like to me that you just need to filter for people in `Staff` whose office location is `Poole Office`, otherwise there is something missing here.

Comment: What would you expect this to return? `SELECT Office_Location FROM Office WHERE Office_Location = 'Poole Office'`? You're saying: give me all types of fruit where types of fruit = apples (which returns "Apples", which you already knew). You want to grab the `OfficeID` for the `office_location = 'Poole Office'`. Using that `OfficeID`, you would then figure out the specific expertise within that office (hint: sub query), and finally you then list all the names, id, and expertise of staff matching those (removing the ones in the `Poole Office`.

Comment: Staff.Office_ID = Office.Office_ID

Comment: Start with your base query and work backwards. First you want the Office ID of the Poole Office from the office id table. Then use that to get all expertise from the staff table where the office ID matches, then select all expertise that match the results from query B.

Comment: SELECT S_Name, S_ID, S_Expertise
FROM Staff
WHERE S_Expertise IN(SELECT Office_Location
                     FROM Office
                     WHERE Staff.Office_ID = Office.Office_ID AND Office_Location = 'Poole Office');

Comment: @user3916285 There must be more Details like the Position (near ..)

Answer (score 5):

Break down your problem into specific units that describe what you need and walk through it.  If you skip to the end and just copy the code, you'll never learn, so please walk through this step-by-step.

Challenge:

> List the name, id and expertise of all staff who have the same
>   expertise as those currently in the Poole Office

Facts we need:

> 1) Staff member name
>
> 2) Staff member ID
>
> 3) Staff member expertise
>
> 4) Whether the staff member shares an expertise with another staff
>   member (not himself) who works in the Poole office.

Information we have:

> Staff:
>
> 1) Staff member ID
>
> 2) Staff member name
>
> 3) Staff member expertise
>
> 4) Staff member's office
>
> Office:
>
> 1) office ID
>
> 2) office location

Look at the two tables, and see if you can figure out how they are connected.  Do you see a column that has the same name? If so, use it in a JOIN condition, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Staff
     INNER JOIN 
    Office ON 
        Staff.SomeColumn = Office.SomeColumn
```

Great!  Now we've got a list of all staff members, along with their office.

What next?  Next, we have to match up staff members who are not in the Poole office to staff members who are.  There's something called a "Self JOIN" in SQL, where you actually link a table back to itself.  You can do this by giving it what's called an Alias - another name that your query can use.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Staff StaffNotInPooleOffice
     INNER JOIN 
    Staff StaffInPooleOffice ON 
        ????
```

How do we want to relate these two tables?  Well, what is your condition?  You want staff that share the same expertise.  Oh, and you don't want to return staff members who have the same expertise as themselves - that would be just silly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Staff a -- StaffNotInPooleOffice
     INNER JOIN 
    Staff b --StaffInPooleOffice 
      ON 
        a.S_ID != b.S_ID AND
        a.S_Expertise = b.S_Expertise
```

There's another requirement here, actually.  We want to only return staff that aren't from the Poole office.  Let's go out to the office table now ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Staff a -- StaffNotInPooleOffice
     INNER JOIN 
    Staff b --StaffInPooleOffice 
      ON 
        a.S_ID != b.S_ID AND
        a.S_Expertise = b.S_Expertise
     INNER JOIN 
    Office c ON 
        b.Office_ID = c.Office_ID
WHERE c.Office_Location = 'Poole'
```

Great!  That `WHERE` clause means that the staff in `b` who share an expertise with the staff in `a` must be from the Poole office.  Getting closer!

New problem.  What happens if multiple staff members in Poole share the same expertise?  This query would return them, and that's not what we want, so let's add a new filter or JOIN condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Staff a -- StaffNotInPooleOffice
     INNER JOIN 
    Staff b --StaffInPooleOffice 
      ON 
        a.S_ID != b.S_ID AND
        a.S_Expertise = b.S_Expertise AND
        a.Office_ID != b.Office_ID -- see what I did here?  Now I know that the staff member in a isn't from the same place as the member in b.
     INNER JOIN 
    Office c ON 
        b.Office_ID = c.Office_ID
WHERE c.Office_Location = 'Poole'
```

Much, much closer.  Now I think we've got it, so let's stop using `SELECT *` - if you ever put that into a production environment, your server will blow up and melt your keyboard.  Seriously.  It's a documented feature.

```
SELECT a.S_Name, a.S_ID, a.S_Expertise 
FROM 
    Staff a -- StaffNotInPooleOffice
     INNER JOIN 
    Staff b --StaffInPooleOffice 
      ON 
        a.S_ID != b.S_ID AND
        a.S_Expertise = b.S_Expertise AND
        a.Office_ID != b.Office_ID -- see what I did here?  Now I know that the staff member in a isn't from the same place as the member in b.
     INNER JOIN 
    Office c ON 
        b.Office_ID = c.Office_ID
WHERE c.Office_Location = 'Poole'
```

Is that right?  Well actually, I have no idea!  It's your table, after all.  That's the process of thought that could let you figure out an answer, and if you follow it and CHECK MY CODE to make sure it does what I think it does, you'll do well.

Or, of course, you could just randomly ask people online to do your homework for you.  They have nothing better to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S_Name, S_ID, S_Expertise FROM 
Staff WHERE Office_ID IN(SELECT Office_ID 
FROM Office WHERE Office_Location = 'Poole Office');
```

Comment: All this will give the OP is a list of staff members who work at Poole.

Comment: yes. It will check for the Office_ID of Office_Location and match those with Staff table Office_ID. All the staffs will be shown having Office_Location as 'Poole Office'

Comment: Absolutely!  That's exactly what it does ... which is not what the original question is asking for.

Answer (score -3):

The query you posted can be simplified as

```
SELECT S_Name, S_ID, S_Expertise
FROM Staff
WHERE S_Expertise = 'Poole Office'
```

But I don't think that's te logic you're looking for.
We don't know the column name you're trying to get from Office that should be used to compare it with S_Expertise.
How are we supposed to know that? (referring to your comment "what should it be?)...